# How to make Bootstrap drop down menu slide down on button click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slidedown

im using Bootstrap and I'm trying to declare an event on the drop down menu when a button is clicked. For some odd reason the jquery event isnt triggering. The drop down menu should drop down right under the search query element. 
My JS Fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/sean3200/fNrZ3/ ...Any help would be appreciated.. Thankszz!! Below is some of the code

```
     <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Forbes Clientel</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="active">Home</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="navbar-search">
          <input class="search-query" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
          <div id="drop" class="dropdown">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
              <li>
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a> 
              </li>
              <li>
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a> 
              </li>
              <li>
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <h1>Forbes Clientel</h1>
      <p>FC is a directory of the top forbes earning entrepreneurs</p>
      <input id="myBtn"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Search" type="button"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


//script
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myBtn").click(function(){
                  $("#drop").slidedown();
                })

             })
```

Comment: not sure exactly what you want to do? [is this it?](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/fNrZ3/3/)

Comment: Yes!!, thanks a bunch!.. i forgot that there was other slide methods for this.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eliran Efron said, change JS line 3 to:

```
$("#drop").slideDown();
```

Change HTML line 25-26 to:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul id="drop" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
```

You were referencing the wrong element with your JS, thats all.

Here is your example modified and working: http://jsfiddle.net/fNrZ3/4/

Answer (score 1):

First: the function is named `.slideDown()`
the capital d there can make a hugh change... (working or not, don't forget it's a function you are calling).

from what i saw on the JS console in chrome, i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slidedown'` so it is definitely got something to do with the name so change it to the one with the capital D.

from there i guess it's mostly some settings for the design...
you can try looking here in the Demos and use some of it:
[.slideDown() jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".btn-group").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('open')){
            $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp();
        }else{
            $(".dropdown-menu").slideDown();
        }
    });    
});

$(document).on('click.dropdown.data-api', function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp();
});
```